# GroupTable in ViewController with Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uitableviewsectionheader

I put **Table** in my *ViewController*. I made GroupTable. So, I select the table and choose "**Grouped**" in style in Attribute Inspector.

```
 var TableArray = [["Home","Apple","Orange","Pineapple"],["Flour","Cake Flour"]] 

 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return TableArray.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    debugPrint(TableArray[section].count)

    return TableArray[section].count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row], for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.imageView?.image = menuIconImage[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = TableArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.blue
    tableView.rowHeight = 56.0;

    return cell

}
```

When I run the app, the table only shows "Home","Apple","Orange","Pineapple". 
It does **not show** "Flour", "Cake Flour". 
I don't know where the problem is. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is wrong, the default value is 1.

The Swift 3 syntax is:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return TableArray.count
}
```

According to the naming convention variable names should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Yes bro @vadian. But, I want 2 sections. One Section includes --> "Home","Apple","Orange","Pineapple". Second Section includes --> "Flour", "Cake Flour". How can I do this? bro

Comment: You are using the wrong API. Replace your method with the method in my answer.

Comment: Bro @vadian, your code works for me... Thanks a million bro !!!! :) :) :)